# Spring @Scheduled need to run only 4 times a year?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am implementing Spring scheduling task using @Scheduled annotation.  here is the situation. i need to run task only 4 times a year on specific dates like..

Feb 15,May 15,Aug 15,Nov 15. how can i do that.

can please some one point me in some direction ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Scheduled(cron="0 0 15 2,5,8,11 *")
public void runQuarterly() {...}`

Will run at midnight for the specified dates